# Close all submenus when user clicks somewhere on the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following simple jQuery menu which you can also find in the JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ogbn8x6v/5/):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main_menu_01, .main_menu_02").on('click', function () {
      var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
      if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
        $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500);
        $(this).hasClass('main_menu_01') ? $('.menu').removeClass('active') : $(this).removeClass('active');
      } else {
        $panel.slideDown(500);
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.main_menu_01 {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}

.main_menu_02 {
 padding-left: 5%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_01{
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_02{
 padding-left: 10%;
 background: lime;
}

 .main_menu_01:before, .main_menu_02:before {
 content:'+';
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.main_menu_01.active:before, .main_menu_02.active:before {
 content:'-';
}

.content {
  margin-top: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="main_menu_01 menu"> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="main_menu_02 menu"> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 
      </ul> 
  </ul>
  
<div class="content">
<p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

As you can see in the code I use `slideUp` and `slideDown` to close/open the `submenus`. 
 All this works fine.

---

Now, I want that when the user clicks **anywhere** on the page `submenus` close automatically, because right now the user always has to click on `.main_menu_01 menu` to close all `submenus`.

What do I need to change in my code to make this work?

Comment: Trap the click event on body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/ogbn8x6v/9/

Just add `e.stopPropagation()` and then add event listener to the body :)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main_menu_01, .main_menu_02, .panel").on('click', function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
      var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
      if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
        $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500);
        $(this).hasClass('main_menu_01') ? $('.menu').removeClass('active') : $(this).removeClass('active');
      } else {
        $panel.slideDown(500);
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });
    
    $("body").on('click', function () {
      var $panel = $('.panel');
      if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
        $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500);
        $('main_menu_01').removeClass('active');
        $('.menu').removeClass('active');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.main_menu_01 {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}

.main_menu_02 {
 padding-left: 5%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_01{
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_02{
 padding-left: 10%;
 background: lime;
}

 .main_menu_01:before, .main_menu_02:before {
 content:'+';
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.main_menu_01.active:before, .main_menu_02.active:before {
 content:'-';
}

.content {
  margin-top: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="main_menu_01 menu"> 1.0 Main Menu </li>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="main_menu_02 menu"> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 
      </ul> 
  </ul>
  
<div class="content">
<p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

Note: 
I also added `.panel` to your event listener selector, so that when you click inside the panel the menu does not close.

Comment: I further developed the menu with your code and another issue appeared. Maybe you also have an idea for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444270/minus-sign-of-submenu-does-not-switch-back-to-a-plus-sign-if-menu-is-closed

Answer (score 0):

Using wraping div of menu, check click on `DOM` and close menu using below **jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main_menu_01, .main_menu_02").on('click', function () {
      var $panel = $(this).next('.panel');
      if ($panel.is(':visible')) {
        $panel.add($panel.find('.panel')).slideUp(500);
        $(this).hasClass('main_menu_01') ? $('.menu').removeClass('active') : $(this).removeClass('active');
      } else {
        $panel.slideDown(500);
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    });

 $('html').click(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).closest(".new").length === 0){
   $('.panel').slideUp(500);
      $('.menu').removeClass('active')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.panel{ 
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 0%;
 font-weight: bold;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:none;
}

.main_menu_01 {
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: blue;
}

.main_menu_02 {
 padding-left: 5%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_01{
 padding-left: 1%;
 background: lime;
}

.sub_menu_02{
 padding-left: 10%;
 background: lime;
}

 .main_menu_01:before, .main_menu_02:before {
 content:'+';
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.main_menu_01.active:before, .main_menu_02.active:before {
 content:'-';
}

.content {
  margin-top: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new">
<div class="main_menu_01 menu"> 1.0 Main Menu </div>
  <ul class="panel">
        
    <li class="sub_menu_01"> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
     
    <li class="main_menu_02 menu"> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
      <ul class="panel">
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.1 Sub Menu </a> </li>
        <li class="sub_menu_02"> <a> 1.2.2 Sub Menu </a> </li> 
      </ul> 
  </ul>
  
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```